# Dedicated Server Specification Advice for MYSQL/PHP Website

Tags: mysql, linux, architecture, specifications

Im buying a dedicated server to run an existing website which receives 90,000 visitors per day.  The specification is below.  The website isnt too complicated, mainly mysql searches of a table containing 60,000 records, but will have quite a lot of images (average  of 90kb each in size) stored directly on the file system (not in the db).

Do you think this server spec should be easily able to handle the users  if the website is well design and mysql queries optimised?

Im not too sure about the hard drive configuration and would prefer 15k sas drives instead of 7.2k, but this server spec needs to have 2 internal and 12 other hard drives, and upgarding these all to 600GB SAS 15K drives is to expensive for me.  Would it be beneficial to me to upgrade to 2 x 600gb 15k internal drives and the other 12 leave as 2TB SAS 7,200 RPM ?.   Would my website be able to take advantage of the higher speed drives?  Im not too familar with server configurations as I am mainly a website developer.

Model: Dell PowerEdge D5-880X Carbon-Neutral Server 
Operating System: CentOS Linux 6.x (cPanel/Plesk Compatible)
Control Panel: CPanel [Unlimited Users] - Linux Only
CPU: 2 x 6Core Intel® Xeon® X5650 2.66Ghz
Memory: 48GB DDR3 ECC Memory
Hard Disk Configuration: 2 x 300GB SAS + 12 x 2TB SAS 7,200 RPM
Raid: H700 Advanced Hardware Raid - Raid 10
Dedicated Bandwidth: 10Gbps with 40TB/Month

Answer (score 1):

having the 2 SAS 15k drives would be benificial for the MySQL Server as well as the overall operating system performance as long as you use the SATA Drives for storage only.

As for the rest of the configuration: the server should easily be able to handle this workload.

Answer (score 0):

That looks to be a good spec machine. The 48GB of ram will be especially useful, so make sure you give the Mysql InnoDB Buffer Pool plenty of RAM to use, so that it will always keep the database in memory. That alone can speed up a site significantly.

As for the images, even 100,000 would be barely 10GB of disk space, but it would be useful none the less to split them into subdirectories so that they are not all in the same directory. As an example a file called 1234567890.jpg could be put into a directory like this: 12/34/56/1234567890.jpg - three level hierarchy, with less than 1000 in the final location. This will speed up access through the directory searching which can be a real overhead.

If you have a lot more than 100,000 images, then the hierarchy would be even more important, or maybe even going for some kind of DB-based system such as using S3, or something like MogileFS which does much the same locally.